# how to resize font to match the width on flash textInput component

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

i work with actionscript  2.0 and i add inputtext to the stage from the components

i set the width to 120px 
i want to decrese the font size if it overflow the width of the textinout

how can i accomplish it ?

autosize dosent work.
this method also dosent work, because its inputtext component not text field

```
    txtCurrency.text  = currency;
txtPrice.autosize =  "right"; 
//You set this according to your TextField's dimensions
var maxTextWidth:Number = 75; 


var f:TextFormat = txtPrice.getTextFormat();

//decrease font size until the text fits  
while (txtPrice.textWidth > maxTextWidth || txtPrice.textHeight > maxTextHeight) 
{
    f.size = int(f.size) - 1;
    txtPrice.setTextFormat(f);
}
```

Comment: In your question you say you "work with actionscript 2.0" but the tags for you question are "actionscript-3" and "adobe-flash-cs5". Are you using AS2 or AS3?

Answer (score 0):

try adding 
`txtCurrency.text  = currency;`
inside the while loop after
 `txtPrice.setTextFormat(f);`